# Problem with opening order on binance python

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

i am reviving signal to open order in this format : 'SELL', '1INCHUSDTPERP', '0.6396', '0.652392', '0.588432'. 1- side 2 - symbol 3 - order price 4 - stoploss price 5 - takeprofit price. Than i round all prices in this way:

```
tick = get_ticksize(symbol)
price = round_step_size(float(price), float(tick))
stopl = round_step_size(float(stopl), float(tick))
takep = round_step_size(float(takep), float(tick))
```

get_ticksize function:

```
def get_ticksize(symbol):
    info = client.futures_exchange_info()
    for item in info['symbols']:
        if(item['symbol'] == symbol):
            for f in item['filters']:
                if f['filterType'] == 'PRICE_FILTER':
                    return f['tickSize']
```

And than i am opening orders:

```
stop = client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side="SELL", type="STOP_MARKET", stopPrice=stopl, closePosition="true")
take = client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side="SELL", type="TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET", stopPrice=takep, closePosition="true")
buyorder = client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type="LIMIT", quantity=q, price=price, timeInForce="GTC")
```

so we have input

> 'SELL', '1INCHUSDTPERP', '0.6396', '0.652392', '0.588432'

and output

> SELL 1INCHUSDT 0.6396 0.6523 0.5884

Stoploss and takeprofit opens without any problem but order not opening:

```
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset.
```

Comment: What the value of the q variable ?

Answer (score -1):

Please use decimal.Decimal instead of float.

Besides, I have shared code here to provide my binance client a year ago, and it still runs now: [webtul/binancecli.py](https://github.com/zagfai/webtul/blob/master/webtul/binancecli.py). Your could get a ref.

Comment: Sorry, i cant understand. Can you give me an example or fix my rounding or what? I can't understand where is problem. Why stop and take opens in this way?